# bash print given script argument

Tags: bash

I need to print the argument number of which user types in. No matter what I do I always get just an empty line

```
echo "Give argument number"
read number
allV=$@
echo ${allV[$number]}
```

what is wrong with this few lines? Even if I start the script with a few arguments and I just manually write sth like"

```
echo ${allV[1]}
```

again all I get is an empty line.

Comment: Your assignment to `allV` does not create an array; therefore, indexing it like an array doesn't help.  Use `allV=( "$@" )` and `echo "${allV[$number]}"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bash lets you use an indirect reference, which works also on numbered parameters:

```
echo "${!number}"
```

It also lets you slice the argument list:

```
echo "${@:$number:1}"
```

Or you could copy the arguments into an array:

```
argv=("$@")
echo "${argv[number]}"
```

In all cases, the quotes are almost certainly required, in case the argument includes whitespace and/or glob characters.

Answer (score 1):

To handle `$@` as an array, just change it to `("$@")` :

```
echo "Give argument number"
read number
allV=("$@")
echo ${allV[$number-1]}
```